# List of lists and integers into list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of lists that includes integers and I need to convert it into a single list.

If the list did not include any integers (only other lists) I could use the solution provided here: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

i.e.,

```
[item for sublist in main_list for item in sublist]
```

e.g,

```
test_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14]]
test_list = [item for sublist in test_list for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

However, this solution does not work if the list has integers in it:

```
test_list_2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0, [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14]]
test_list_2 = [item for sublist in test_list_2 for item in sublist]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-28-c6531e09f706>", line 1, in <module>
test_list_2 = [item for sublist in test_list_2 for item in sublist]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Thanks.

Comment: To me, it looks like an architectural problem. Couldn't you just add lists with a single element in the first place?

Comment: @SBI the sublists are added in a for loop for each analysis, the integers ('0s' in my case) are added if the `try` sequence failed and

Comment: So the single digit appearing is always a zero? Could you just avoid adding the value if the try fails? Or instead of adding it directly, adding it to a list?

Comment: instead of adding `0` or whatever why not add `[0,]` or `[]` if the "try sequence failed"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to do something like this:

```
>>> test_list_2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0, [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14]]
>>> def lift_int(v):
...     if not isinstance(v, list): 
...         return [v]
...     else:
...         return v
... 
>>> test_list_2 = [item for sublist in test_list_2 for item in lift_int(sublist)]
>>> test_list_2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Two many answer didn't want to add one more and there is probably as duplicate somewhere so edit yours hope you don't mind

Comment: @user3100115 Just add an answer of your own :)

Comment: That flatten computes a different function. It flattens recursively whereas the asker's code only flattens one level.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to flatten your list I think the best way to do this is using [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/functional.html#generators). Note that this flatten recursively your list not just one level.

```
>>> def flatten(items):
...     for item in items:
...         if isinstance(item, list):
...             yield from flatten(item)
...         else:
...             yield item
... 
>>> list(flatten(test_list_2))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to continue with the list (in)comprehension, you could do this:

```
test_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0, [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14]]
print [item for sublist in test_list for item in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])]

test_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0, [7,8,9,10], 1, 2, 3, [11,12,13,14], 1234]
print [item for sublist in test_list for item in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])]
```

to make it even harder to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
def convert_to_list(num):
    return [num] if not isinstance(num, list) else num
```

Then use `itertools`

```
>>>import itertools
itertools.chain(*map(convert_to_list, test_list_2))
<itertools.chain at 0x7ff211650550>
>>>list(itertools.chain(*map(convert_to_list, test_list_2)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(data):
    result = []
    for sublist in test_list_2:
        if type(sublist) is list:
            result += sublist
        else:
            result.append(sublist)
    return result
```

The convert function convert  the list of lists and integers into a list

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use:

```
test_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x + (y if isinstance(y, list) else [y]), test_list)
```